# Initialize thread won't print anything

Tags: c#, debugging, xna, monogame

Printing works fine in other methods but it won't work in the initialize() thread. Does not matter if I put it before or after the base.Initialize.

```
    protected override void Initialize() {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        Debug.WriteLine("hellO");

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in there? Maybe it's actually being hit, but Debug.WriteLine simply doesn't write anything in the output window?

Answer (score 0):

`Debug.WriteLine()` actually sends to the Windows debug system not to a console output window.  The `Debug` class only writes when the DEBUG condition is set.  By default this is **Debug** builds.  **Release** builds do nothing because by default this conditional is not set.

You'll need a tool like:

- Dbmon.exe
- DbgView
- or run it through the debugger in Visual Studio